# How do I get previous pagination data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I try something like that

```
User::paginate(10);
```

And when I click `2` via my view it's go `/?page=2` and it's just show after record `10`. How do I get previous pagination data?

Why I want to get the previous data? Don't want to go with 1,2,3, pagination. Want to show 10 records, 20 records, 30 records and etc.

Comment: Could you explain what you want in more detail? The idea of pagination is to show the next set of results, why would you want to get the previous page's data?

Comment: To choose 10, 20, 30 ... 100 and All via select and to display to the user. @natzim

Comment: Can you see my updated question @natzim ?

Comment: My answer covers this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the page size in the dropdown menu (lets say the field name is `pageSize`)you want to send the request to the controller again, query the data and paginate with the selected value.

```
User::paginate(Input:get('pageSize', 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view, change:

```
$users->render();
```

to:

```
$users->appends(['foo' => 'bar'])->render();
```

Where you obviously replace `foo` and `bar` with the data you want to passed to the rest of the pages.

[Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links)